# es2015 map doesn't support array of object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Created a jsbin to demo the error, you can see the error here https://jsbin.com/muhuxunome/1/edit

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const normalizedStats = [
  {
    "name": "Confirmed",
    "count": 7
  },
  {
    "name": "Unprocessed",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "Not Suitable",
    "count": 9
  },
  {
    "name": "Shortlisted",
    "count": 17
  }
];

    return(
            <div>
            normalizedStats.map(obj => 
                <li>{obj.name} ({obj.count})</li>
            )
            </div>
        )
  }
}
```

I got error of obj is not defined? I tried lodash's map it worked, not sure why map of es2015 has error here.

Comment: What is the error? Please post it with your question.

Comment: Please show the lodash code that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the "{}"

```
return (
    <div>
        {normalizedStats.map((obj, index) => {
            return <li key={index}>{obj.name} ({obj.count})</li>;
        })}
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use curly braces whenever you want to do JavaScript interpolation in your JSX.

Change

```
normalizedStats.map(obj => 
  <li>{obj.name} ({obj.count})</li>
)
```

to

```
{normalizedStats.map(obj => 
  <li>{obj.name} ({obj.count})</li>
)}
```

Comment: how to sort by order if I have it in my array of object? https://pastebin.com/raw/HtCc6pXT

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the map result within `{}`. You need to do that in order to render your elements within JSX. Also ideally should be adding a key to the retuned JSX elements from map

```
 {normalizedStats.map(obj => 
            <li key={obj.name}>{obj.name} ({obj.count})</li>
        )}
```

Code with sorting

```
class Image extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return <img className="center" {...this.props} />;
  }
}

Image.propTypes = {
  src: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const normalizedStats = [
  {
    "name": "Confirmed",
    "count": 7
  },
  {
    "name": "Unprocessed",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "Not Suitable",
    "count": 9
  },
  {
    "name": "Shortlisted",
    "count": 17
  }
];
   normalizedStats.sort(function(a, b) {return a.count - b.count})
    return(
            <div>
      {normalizedStats.map((obj) =>  {
              return <li key={obj.name}>{obj.name} ({obj.count})</li>
            }

            )}
            </div>
        )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: 'JSBin'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (<div className="app">
        <Hello />
      </div>);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

**[JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/wowarijuge/1/edit?html,js,output)**

Comment: You dont chain it, you sort and then map, you can do it in the render function. On what basis you wanna sort